# 3D plot of bivariate distribution using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a bivariate distribution with the following parameters:

```
Ux = 0.487889
Uy = 0.483756
Var(X) = 0.094482
Var(Y) = 0.073845
Covar(X,Y) = 0.078914
```

How do I make a 3d surface plot of this using python?

Comment: There are infinitely many distributions which would satisfy those parameters. Which of them would you like to plot?

Answer (score 2):

As the comment suggests, there are literally an infinite number of ways to answer this question. It's important to show the code you have tried so far, and provide the context, so that contributors can best help you. I used PyCharm 2018.2.4 and Python 3.6. The following code assumes quite a bit, and does not include the covariance you provided, but it might get you going in the right direction:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#Parameters to set
mu_x = 0.487889
variance_x = 0.094482

mu_y = 0.483756
variance_y = 0.073845

#Create grid and multivariate normal
x = np.linspace(-0.5,1.5,500)
y = np.linspace(-0.5,1.5,500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X; pos[:, :, 1] = Y
rv = multivariate_normal([mu_x, mu_y], [[variance_x, 0], [0, variance_y]])

#Make a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, rv.pdf(pos),cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
plt.show()
```

This provides the following graph:

[image: Bivariate Distribution From Python using PyCharm]